# Print WPF Visuals with MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, printing, datagrid

My ViewModel has a PrintCommand executing a Method called PrintCalendar(). But the Calendar aka datagrid is in the View, so how do I get my datagrid into the ViewModel?

Getting my hands dirty and do all that stuff in code-behind? oh no...

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
printDlg.PrintVisual(datagrid, "Grid Printing.");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this. I have set up a simple demo window with a datagrid, a buttom and a ViewModel. The ViewModel contains the PrintCommand (a RelayCommand from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)) which accepts a Visual (the datagrid) as the command parameter. There is no code in the code behind all the work is done via binding.

The Xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication.ViewModel"
    x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:WindowViewModel x:Key="WindowViewModel"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{DynamicResource WindowViewModel}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Content="Print" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{Binding PrintCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" DataContext="{DynamicResource SampleDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

namespace WpfTestApplication.ViewModel
{
    public class WindowViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Command executed to print an visual component. The component is passed in as a parameter.
        /// </summary>
        public RelayCommand<Visual> PrintCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<Visual>( v =>
                {
                    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
                    printDlg.PrintVisual( v, "Grid Printing." );
                } );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are tracking me eh? ;-) of course what you say is right. You just pass the object to the ViewModel. My requirments changed so I have to do a lot of technical stuff in codebehind to print a page with datagrid + richtext. Do you know how to print a page composed by many controls?

Comment: No not tracking you, just saw you had one unanswered question :) What do you mean by on one page? Do you mean composing the print output using a number of controls from different parts of the UI?

Comment: Technically, this example is breaking the MVVM pattern. Typically, you want to avoid using WPF objects, like `PrintDialog`, in your view model. However, cases like this where you need to use a WPF dialog control and call a method on it simply don't fit the MVVM pattern very well, so you have to make a choice to either color outside the lines a bit in your view model or just use leave this kind of stuff in the code-behind

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need the following to be able to show the print dialog box as well:

```
public RelayCommand<Visual> PrintCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<Visual>( v =>
        {
            PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(myPrintDialog.ShowDialog()))
            {
                printDlg.PrintVisual( v, "Grid Printing." );
            }
        });
    }
}
```