# print WPF visual from viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, printing

how do i print a visual or window from the ViewModel by just calling a method to print without using a RelayCommand as shown in this example: [Print WPF Visuals with MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875789/print-wpf-visuals-with-mvvm-pattern)?

```
var printDlg = new PrintDialog();
printDlg.PrintVisual(View, "JOB PRINTING")
```

Comment: Why do you want to make your ViewModel aware of your View if you are using MVVM?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a Command? Well you can always bind the view to a property in your view model. I would propably use an attached behavior for that. Making the command an attached property, on the element, bind the command OneWayToSource to the view model, fire it there, and handle it on the control itself via the attached behavior.

Comment: i want to print the document/window after a certain event has occurred..so the printing is not being invoked with a RelayCommand, and the event/condition occurs in code..not on the view/xaml

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a quick and dirty but reusable attached behavior class. 
Disclaimer: I just hacked this in a couple of minutes and it has its flaws, which should be easy to overcome.

First we need our service class.

```
public class VisualPrinter
{
    private static RoutedUICommand PrintVisualCommand = new RoutedUICommand("PrintVisualCommand", "PrintVisualCommand", typeof(VisualPrinter));

    #region ab PrintCommand

    public static ICommand GetPrintCommand(DependencyObject aTarget)
    {
        return (ICommand)aTarget.GetValue(PrintCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPrintCommand(DependencyObject aTarget, ICommand aValue)
    {
        aTarget.SetValue(PrintCommandProperty, aValue);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrintCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PrintCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(VisualPrinter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PrintVisualCommand));

    #endregion

    #region ab EnablePrintCommand

    public static bool GetEnablePrintCommand(DependencyObject aTarget)
    {
        return (bool)aTarget.GetValue(EnablePrintCommandProperty);
    }
    public static void SetEnablePrintCommand(DependencyObject aTarget, bool aValue)
    {
        aTarget.SetValue(EnablePrintCommandProperty, aValue);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnablePrintCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnablePrintCommand", typeof(bool), typeof(VisualPrinter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnablePrintCommandChanged));

    private static void OnEnablePrintCommandChanged(DependencyObject aDependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs aArgs)
    {
        var newValue = (bool)aArgs.NewValue;
        var element = aDependencyObject as UIElement;
        if(newValue)
        {
            element.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(PrintVisualCommand, OnPrintVisual));
        }
    }

    private static void OnPrintVisual(object aSender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs aE)
    {
        // the element is the one were you set the EnablePrintCommand
        var element = aSender as Visual;
        var printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        // do the printing
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here we define two attached properties. `PrintCommand` is used to inject the actual print command into a view model, this must be done with OneWayToSource.
The second, `EnablePrintCommand`, is to enable the printing, setting which element should be printed and to register the command binding.

My current version has a flaw, that you can't set both properties on the same element, but this can easily be overcome. So to print a a button, it would look like this:

```
<Grid local:VisualPrinter.EnablePrintCommand="True">
    <Button Content="Test" local:VisualPrinter.PrintCommand="{Binding ViewModelPrint, Mode=OneWayToSource">
</Grid>
```

While `ViewModelPrint` is a property of type ICommand in the view model, which can be executed and will then print the grid(therefore the button).