# printdialogue from view model in wpf

Tags: mvvm, printing, viewmodel

I have a requirement as follows, I want to print the screen elements present on the screen to printer. Implementation is done through MVVM. so If I click on print button on the screen it should display a print dialogue and selecting the printer should proceed with printing all the UI elemnts with their data . I have tried with solution present at [print WPF visual from viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876478/print-wpf-visual-from-viewmodel) but its missing the margings and not displaying properly

Also I have another button Print Preview which should display print preview dialogue to see the preiview.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Krishna.

Comment: Printing the UI is not the concern of the ViewModel.  Simply implement the print method in the codebehind, where you have access to all your UI elements.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the printing of the View in an MVVM application is not the responsiblity or concern of the ViewModel. I believe you are better of doing this from the View.

How I've achieved this before is to use a WPF Behavior on a button  - I use a Behavior because I'm using DataTemplates for the View and there isn't a 'code behind' file.

The Behavior exposes a DependencyProperty, this is a binding to what is to be printed or contains what is going to be printed.

XAML:

```
<Button Margin="0,2,5,2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Content="PRINT"
        ToolTip="Prints the current report">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:ReportPrintClickBehavior Content="{Binding ElementName=SelectedReportContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

To reference the Behavior in the XAML you'll need to reference System.Windows.Interactivity, this can be found on NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interactivity.Wpf/1.0.1340).

Code-Behind (Behavior):

In this case I'm printing a `FlowDocument` hosted inside a `FlowDocumentReader`.

```
public sealed class ReportPrintClickBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content",
        typeof(DependencyObject),
        typeof(ReportPrintClickBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DependencyObject Content
    {
        get { return (DependencyObject)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= OnUnloaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var flowDocumentReader = Content.GetVisualDescendent<FlowDocumentReader>();
        if (flowDocumentReader != null)
        {
            flowDocumentReader.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and it should be okfor me. I have another thing remaining as a seperate option is about displaying a print preview, how can we get that in this approach

Comment: you don't, and to be honest you don't need it as the WPF prints the output as WYSIWYG

Comment: My bad..I am working on a Windows Forms to WPF migration project and they had that option in their classic Forms based version and they are expecting to have the same feature in WPF project as well and I am stuck here..But many thanks for all your responses